# How to implement text search in html and get the xpath of the DOM element containing the text?

Tags: javascript, html, css, xpath, browser

My webpage has a set of `div`s overlapping each other and but with different `z-index` values. I am trying to implement a text search functionality so that when the text is found in a `div`, I can bring that `div` to the foreground. Something like flipping the pages of a book to the page containing the text.

One way to do this would be to loop through the innerHTMLs of all the text DOM elements in each `div` and then using the `xpath` of each resultant element to determine which `div` it belongs to and bringing that `div` to the foreground. But it would be highly inefficient.

Rather I am wondering if there is some way to delegate this task to the browser itself. I tried text searching in Chrome, firefox, safari etc.. They found the text even in the hidden `div`s. Is there any way I can refer to those search results to determine the `xpath` of the results?

Basically do browsers provide us with any APIs that can help me?

Thanx in advance!!

**Note:** I am looking for a pure javascript solution or at best I can use google closure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery plugin: Search engine:

```
$('div').searchengine(myText,'html',false);
```

- All divs selected
- myText : text that I search on Divs
- 'html' : Using html method, it can be `'val'` method if its input or `'text'` method if its pre ,...etc

Adding this plugin after loading jQuery

```
$.fn.searchengine = function(text, action, casesensitive, exactText) {

        var arrayJq = []

        var all = $(this);
        all.each(function() {

            var html = $(this).html();
            var vll = $(this).val();
            var ttx = $(this).text();
            if (casesensitive === false) {
                html = html.toLocaleLowerCase();
                vll = vll.toLocaleLowerCase();
                ttx = ttx.toLocaleLowerCase();
                text = text.toLocaleLowerCase();
            }
            var test;
            if (exactText = true) {
                test = (html === text) || (vll === text) || (ttx === text)
            } else {
                test = (html.indexOf(text) !== -1)
                        || (vll.indexOf(text) !== -1)
                        || (ttx.indexOf(text) !== -1)
            }
            if (test === true) {
                arrayJq.push($(this));
                if (action.length !== 0) {
                    $(this)[action]();
                }

            }
        })
        return arrayJq;

    };
```

**Update:**

To get th xpath, you can use fullselector jQuery plugin :

```
$('div#myDiv').fullselector();
```

known that you must add this code after jQuery loading :

```
$.fn.id=function(){
        var arr=[];
        if($(this).length>0){
            arr.push($(this).get(0).tagName.toLocaleLowerCase());
            $(this).parents().each(function(i,e){
                var ind=$(e).index();
                ind='['+ind+']';
                arr.push($(e).get(0).tagName.toLocaleLowerCase()+ind)});
               arr.reverse();
        }

            return arr.join('//');

    };
    /**
     * Full jquery selector of element 
     * @depend of $.id() jquery plugi
     */
    $.fn.fullselector=function(){
        var arr=[];
        if($(this).get(0)){
            arr.push($(this).get(0).tagName.toLocaleLowerCase());
        }

        $(this).parents().each(function(i,e){
            //var ind=mthpathid.indexChildsametag($(e).parent(),$(e))
            var ind=$(e).index();
            ind=':eq('+ind+')';
            if($(e).get(0).tagName.toLocaleLowerCase()=='html'){
                arr.push($(e).get(0).tagName.toLocaleLowerCase()+ind)
            }else{
                arr.push(ind)
            }
            });arr.reverse();
            return arr.join('>');

    };
var mthpathid={
        indexChildsametag:function(jqparent,jqchild){
            var j=-1;
            jqparent.children(jqchild.get(0).tagName.toLocaleLowerCase()).each(function(i,e){
                if($(e).id()===jqchild.id()){
                     j=i;
                }

            });
            return j;
        }
};
```

Comment: I am sorry, i should have mentioned it earlier but i am looking for a pure javascript solution or at best i can use google closure.

Answer (score 0):

I rustled up an approach I would take to doing a text search.

The basic idea would be that you do the searching without touching the dom, therefore saving quite a bit of processing overhead.

http://jsfiddle.net/j84aX/2/

Basically this is what my example does:

```
//Data comes in the form of an array of objects.

var results = [{
    id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
    title: 'Some sort of title'   
}, {
    id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
    title: 'Some other item'   
}, {
    id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
    title: 'Maybe a thingy'   
}]
```

---

```
// Templates are created and references attached to the original objects
// Templates are attached to the dom

renderResults = function() {
    var i = 0,
        len = results.length,
        item;

    for (; i < len; i++) {
        item = $('<li data-id="'+ results[i].id +'">'+ results[i].title +'</li>');
        results[i].item = item;
        item.appendTo(resultsEl);
    }

    $('body').append(resultsEl);
}
```

---

```
// A user searches and a lookup is done in the result set
$('.search input').on('keyup', function() {

});
```

---

```
// Any matches already have the item on their object and do not need to do a dom lookup
// Matches are highlighted using a class name
for (; i < len; i++) {
    if (results[i].title.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) !== -1) {
        results[i].item.addClass('match')
    }
}
```

Comment: The data gathering part is the most inefficient part of the code, and that is the one I am trying to avoid. According to your method I would still have to parse the whole HTML to form the object JSON. And then I would also need to search through it.

Comment: @SurenderThakran That depends on how you are getting your data into the front end. You are correct though that if your data is not coming from ajax then my solution will not be efficient.

Comment: No my data is not coming from ajax. I would be running my script on a plain old DOM structure.